# how to prevent getting message:Trying to get property of non-object when id is not found

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.4

now I have this controller which gets id from db and than list som information from db. but when I go to database and delete the data manually, the controller can't find the id anymore and it returns :Trying to get property of non-object
with planti of privet information. my conde is something like below:

```
    public function saveChanges(Request $request){
  $id=$request->input('id');

  $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required|min:2'
  ]);


  $post=Post::where('id',$id)->first();
  if($post->id == $id){
  $post->title = $request['title'];
  $post->postBody = $request['body'];



  if ($post->update())
  {
    return response()->json([
      'type'=>1,
      'newtitle'=>$post->title,
      'newbody'=>$post->postBody
    ]);
  }
  else{
    return response()->json(['type'=>0]);
  }
}

else {
  echo"404";
}

}
```

the thing I don't like here is going for the id directly like this:

```
$post=Post::where('id',$id)->first();
```

I don't have much idea about laravel so do you think I may prevent this situation by any chance?

Comment: Well check if you have a valid object first, before trying to call any methods on it ...

Comment: @CBroe I see. My knowladge is just not enough in terms of syntax to do that

Comment: do you think `if($post=Post::where('id',$id)->first() != null)` is gonna work?

Comment: No, `Post::where('id',$id)->first()` is still the same method call, and will fail the same way, if `Post::where('id',$id)` did not return an actual object. You need to check what `Post::where('id',$id)` resulted in first, and if that is a valid object, then you can call the method on it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, check first if a post was found before trying to access a property:

```
$post = Post::where('id',$id)->first();

if ($post instanceof Post && $post->id == $id) {
    // ...
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Comment: yeah I got the point. now it doesnt fail and returns the else instead

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if object Post exists, for example by function is_object()
http://php.net/is_object